# Enclosing variables within for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, lazy-evaluation

So consider the following chunk of code which does not work as most people might expect it to

```
#cartoon example
a <- c(3,7,11)
f <- list()

#manual initialization
f[[1]]<-function(x) a[1]+x
f[[2]]<-function(x) a[2]+x
f[[3]]<-function(x) a[3]+x

#desired result for the rest of the examples
f[[1]](1)
# [1] 4
f[[3]](1)
# [1] 12

#attempted automation
for(i in 1:3) {
   f[[i]] <- function(x) a[i]+x
}

f[[1]](1)
# [1] 12
f[[3]](1)
# [1] 12
```

Note that we get 12 both times after we attempt to "automate". The problem is, of course, that `i` isn't being enclosed in the function's private environment. All the functions refer to the same `i` in the global environment (which can only have one value) since a for loop does not seem to create different environment for each iteration.

```
sapply(f, environment)
# [[1]]
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
# [[2]]
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
# [[3]]
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

So I though I could get around with with the use of `local()` and `force()` to capture the `i` value

```
for(i in 1:3) {
   f[[i]] <- local({force(i); function(x) a[i]+x})
}

f[[1]](1)
# [1] 12
f[[3]](1)
# [1] 12
```

but this still doesn't work. I can see they all have different environments (via `sapply(f, environment)`) however they appear to be empty (`ls.str(envir=environment(f[[1]]))`). Compare this to

```
for(i in 1:3) {
   f[[i]] <- local({ai<-i; function(x) a[ai]+x})
}

f[[1]](1)
# [1] 4
f[[3]](1)
# [1] 12

ls.str(envir=environment(f[[1]]))
# ai :  int 1
ls.str(envir=environment(f[[3]]))
# ai :  int 3
```

So clearly the `force()` isn't working like I was expecting. I was assuming it would capture the current value of `i` into the current environment. It is useful in cases like

```
#bad
f <- lapply(1:3, function(i) function(x) a[i]+x)
#good
f <- lapply(1:3, function(i) {force(i); function(x) a[i]+x})
```

where `i` is passed as a parameter/promise, but this must not be what's happening in the for-loop.

So my question is: is possible to create this list of functions without `local()` and variable renaming? Is there a more appropriate function than `force()` that will capture the value of a variable from a parent frame into the local/current environment?

Comment: Can you please clarify why you are not happy with variable renaming I mean the solution: `f[[i]] <- local({ai<-i; function(x) a[ai]+x})` ?

Comment: It's not so much as it makes me unhappy as much as if that's the only way, I don't understand why it's the only way. Why must I rename? Is there no way to set things up such that I don't have to rename (I just want to grab a copy of the variable with the same name like I can do in the `lapply` versions). Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't a complete answer, partly because I'm not sure exactly what the question is (even though I found it quite interesting!).

Instead, I'll just present two alternative `for`-loops that do work. They've helped clarify the issues in my mind (in particular by helping me to understand for the first time why `force()` does anything at all in a call to  `lapply()`).  I hope they'll help you as well.

First, here is one that's a much closer equivalent of your properly function `lapply()` call, and which works for the same reason that it does:

```
a <- c(3,7,11)
f <- list()

## `for` loop equivalent of:
## f <- lapply(1:3, function(i) {force(i); function(x) a[i]+x})
for(i in 1:3) {
    f[[i]] <- {X <- function(i) {force(i); function(x) a[i]+x}; X(i)}
}
f[[1]](1)
# [1] 4
```

Second, here is one that does use `local()` but doesn't (strictly- or literally-speaking) rename `i`. It does, though, "rescope" it, by adding a copy of it to the local environment. In one sense, it's only trivially different from your functioning `for`-loop, but by focusing attention on `i`'s scope, rather than its name, I think it helps shed light on the real issues underlying your question.

```
a <- c(3,7,11)
f <- list()

for(i in 1:3) {
   f[[i]] <- local({i<-i; function(x) a[i]+x})
}
f[[1]](1)
# [1] 4
```

Comment: I think both of these capture exactly what I was trying to do. In fact, i thought i already had tried the `i<-i` method but must have gotten an unrelated error in my test. I guess the important part is that `force()` doesn't do any sort of capture/assignment, it just evaluates promises. At least that's how i'm currently understanding things.

Comment: @MrFlick -- Here are my thoughts on the role of `force()`. I personally wasn't surprised that `force(i)` didn't work in your `for` loop, since like you said, it just evaluates `i`. (`force`, after all, is just `function(x) x` by another name!) Without being assigned to any symbol, the returned value just disappears into the ether.

Comment: When you've got nested functions (as in your `lapply()` call or my `for`-loop equivalent), matters are a bit different. In that case, the `i` that's being referenced is a supplied argument to a standard R function, and as such, it's initiated as a promise. When it's subsequently `force()`'d in the body of the top-level function, the then-current value of `i` (ultimately gotten from the index of the `lapply()` or `for`-loop) gets bound to the promise. Because of R's lexical scoping, that bound value is what's finally found and used by the inner function when it goes looking for the value of `i`

Comment: This is what I was thinking too. Thank you for taking the time to write it out clearly. This inspired me to make the function: `capture <- function(...) {vars<-sapply(substitute(...()), deparse); pf <- parent.frame(); Map(assign, vars, mget(vars, envir=pf, inherits = TRUE), MoreArgs=list(envir=pf))}` which I can then use like `for(i in 1:3) {f[[i]] <- local({capture(i); function(x) a[i]+x})}` (hopefully I didn't reinvent something that already existed).

Answer (score 1):

Will this approach work for you?

```
ff<-list()
for(i in 1:3) {
    fillit <- parse(text=paste0('a[',i,']+x' ))
   ff[[i]] <- function(x) ''
   body(ff[[i]])[1]<-fillit
}
```

It's sort of a lower-level way to construct a function, but it does work "as you want it to."

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for `force()` that would work in a for-loop local environment is

```
capture <- function(...) {
    vars<-sapply(substitute(...()), deparse); 
    pf <- parent.frame(); 
    Map(assign, vars, mget(vars, envir=pf, inherits = TRUE), MoreArgs=list(envir=pf))
 }
```

Which can then be used like

```
for(i in 1:3) {
    f[[i]] <- local({capture(i); function(x) a[i]+x})
}
```

(Taken from the comments in Josh's answer above)