# Create new functions using a list of functions and list of function parameters to Be Passed

Tags: r

I am trying to create new functions from a list of function and a list of parameters to be passed to these functions, but am unable to do so so far. Please see the example below.

```
fun_list <- list(f = function(x, params) {x+params[1]}, 
          z = function(a, params) {a * params[1] * params[2]})
params_list <- list(f = 1, z = c(3, 5))

# goal is to create 2 new functions in global environment
#  fnew <- function(x) {x+1}
#  znew <- function(a) {a*3*5}

# I've tried
for(x in names(fun_list)){
  force(x)
  assign(paste0(x, "new"), function(...) fun_list[[x]] (...,  params = params_list[[x]]))
}
```

The goal is to do this dynamically for arbitrary functions and parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
for(x in names(fun_list)) {
  formals(fun_list[[x]])$params <- params_list[[x]]
  assign(paste0(x, "new"), fun_list[[x]])
}
```

Comment: What a straightforward solution. You are awesome.

Comment: This does change the functions in the original `fun_list` list which may or may not be desirable. You can just make a copy before you change the formals if you like.

Answer (score 7):

Well, `force()` doesn't work in a for-loop because for loops do not create new environments. Based on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064649/enclosing-variables-within-for-loop) of mine, I created a `capture()` function

```
capture <- function(...) {
    vars <- sapply(substitute(...()), deparse); 
    pf <- parent.frame(); 
    Map(assign, vars, mget(vars, envir=pf, inherits = TRUE), MoreArgs=list(envir=pf))
}
```

this allows

```
for(x in names(fun_list)) {
    f = local({ 
           capture(x); 
           p = params_list[[x]]; 
           f = fun_list[[x]]; 
           function(x) f(x, p)
    })
    assign(paste0(x, "new"), f)
}
```

where we create a local, private environment for the functions to store their default parameter values.

Which gives

```
fnew(2)
# [1] 3
znew(2)
# [1] 30
```

Comment: Thanks @Frank. I goofed up in my testing. I've updated the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar in spirit:

```
ps  <- list(fp=1,zp=c(3,5))
f0s <- substitute(list(f=function(x)x+fp,z=function(a)a*zp1*zp2),as.list(unlist(ps))) 
f0s # list(f = function(x) x + 1, z = function(a) a * 3 * 5)

fs  <- eval(f0s)
fs$f(1) # 2
```

To do the fancy thing described in the OP, you'd probably have to mess with `formals`.