# How to create a new data.table object in for loop based off an existing data.table and update columns?

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying emulate the following code

```
compile_1 <- compile_0[, final_1 := ifelse((!is.na(final_0) & is.na(input_1)), final_0, final_1)]
compile_2 <- compile_1[, final_2 := ifelse((!is.na(final_1) & is.na(input_2)), final_1, final_2)]
compile_3 <- compile_2[, final_3 := ifelse((!is.na(final_2) & is.na(input_3)), final_2, final_3)]
```

in a for loop but I am running issues, which I think (but I'm not entirely sure) is because `i` isn't being enclosed in the function's (assign) private environment see [Enclosing variables within for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064649/enclosing-variables-within-for-loop).

My initial attempt at the for loop was

```
for(i in 1:3){
  
  
  assign(paste0("compile_", get("i")-1), get(paste0("compile_", get("i",)-1))[, paste0("final_", get("i")) := ifelse((!is.na(get(paste0("final_", get("i")-1))) & is.na(get(paste0("input_",get("i"))))), get(paste0("final_", get("i")-1)),get(paste0("final_", get("i"))))])
  
  
}
```

I then tried adding a copy of `i` to the local environment as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064649/enclosing-variables-within-for-loop), but this didn't work either, because it is then looking for compile_0 which is not in the function's local environment... i think?

```
dput(head(compile_0[, ..yy],20)) #i have removed some unecessary columns
structure(list(id = c("100", "10000", "10002", "10006", "1000794", 
"10010", "1002162", "1002820", "1003005", "1003330", "1003458", 
"1003617", "1004034", "1004235", "1004649", "1004731", "1004795", 
"1004796", "1004798", "1004799"), final_0 = c(445L, 960L, 655L, 
590L, 550L, 780L, 570L, 200L, 272L, 540L, 550L, 470L, 588L, 320L, 
750L, 500L, 418L, 418L, 438L, 648L), final_1 = c(445L, 960L, 
655L, 590L, 550L, 780L, 570L, 200L, 272L, 540L, 550L, 470L, 588L, 
320L, 750L, 500L, 418L, 418L, 438L, 648L), final_2 = c(460L, 
960L, NA, NA, NA, 780L, 570L, 200L, 200L, 540L, 550L, NA, 568L, 
320L, 705L, 400L, 449L, 449L, 469L, 648L), final_3 = c(460L, 
960L, NA, NA, NA, 780L, 570L, 200L, 200L, 540L, 550L, NA, 568L, 
320L, 705L, 400L, 449L, 449L, 469L, 648L), input_0 = c(445L, 
960L, 655L, 590L, 550L, 780L, 570L, 200L, 272L, 540L, 550L, 470L, 
588L, 320L, 750L, 500L, 418L, 418L, 438L, 648L), input_1 = c(445L, 
960L, 655L, 590L, 550L, 780L, 570L, 200L, 272L, 540L, 550L, 470L, 
588L, 320L, 750L, 500L, 418L, 418L, 438L, 648L), input_2 = c(460L, 
960L, NA, NA, NA, 780L, 570L, 200L, 200L, 540L, 550L, NA, 568L, 
320L, 705L, 400L, 449L, 449L, 469L, 648L), input_3 = c(460L, 
960L, NA, NA, NA, 780L, 570L, 200L, 200L, 540L, 550L, NA, 568L, 
320L, 705L, 400L, 449L, 449L, 469L, 648L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000176df6d1ef0>, sorted = "id")
```

Thanks!

I was expecting the for loop to give the same output as the individual lines of code.

Comment: I just wonder how your data would be changed. Your `compile_0` (the data you provided) already have same values in `final_1`, `final_2`, `final_3` columns, so I don't think your data would be changed if the for loop works.

Comment: I have updated the sample data, the idea is to carry forward the previous `final_` value if there is an NA in `input_`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `eval()` when creating or editing columns in `data.table`.

```
require(data.table)
for(i in 1:3){
  compile_old <- paste0('compile_',i-1)
  compile_new <- paste0('compile_',i)
  final_first <- paste0('final_',i-1)
  final_second <- paste0('final_',i)
  input <- paste0('input_',i)
  
  assign(compile_new, 
         get(compile_old)[,eval(final_second):=ifelse((!is.na(get(final_first) & is.na(get(input)))), get(final_first), get(final_second))])
}
```

Furthermore, You need to keep in mind that after the for loop, `compile_0`, `compile_1`, `compile_2`, and `compile_3` would be the same because of `:=` in `data.table`.

So, you can keep the difference among them with `copy()` for **deep copy**.

```
for(i in 1:3){
  compile_old <- paste0('compile_',i-1)
  compile_new <- paste0('compile_',i)
  final_first <- paste0('final_',i-1)
  final_second <- paste0('final_',i)
  input <- paste0('input_',i)
  
  # copy() for deep copy
  compile_old_copy <- copy(get(compile_old))
  assign(compile_new, 
         compile_old_copy[,eval(final_second):=ifelse((!is.na(get(final_first) & is.na(get(input)))), get(final_first), get(final_second))])
}
```

You can see that all the `compile_{}` are different.

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly!!! Although you had a type in your if condition it should be `(!is.na(get(final_first)) & is.na(get(input)))`

Comment: You certainly do not need `eval`, just use `c`, for example `data.table(mtcars)[, c("c1"):=cyl+1][]`.